# EE or IH Sounds

Tags: pronunciation

Does it seem to me that in some songs words are pronounced differently?
for example (instead of ɪ is heard i) Like in the hook of Vince Staples - Lift Me Up

Comment: What words?  It may surprise you that not everyone knows the hook of Lift Me Up very well. Remember, *songs are not a good source of natural grammar or phrasing since they are written to fit a musical line*.

Comment: Many words are pronounced differently anyway.